# Any *normal* way to use direct rendermode for mobile application in Flash Builder 4.6?

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, air, flash-builder, stage3d

I tried to make a mobile app (air 3.2) utilising Stage3D in Flash Builder 4.6, but whenever I tried to debug the application I got an error saying Stage3D is unavailable.

I had to manually edit bin-debug/MyApp.xml and set `<renderMode>direct</renderMode>` for it to work.

Is there any normal way to select direct render mode in Flash Builder without having to edit app XML manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Unfortunately there is no way "yet" to select render mode in Flash Builder. You have to manually edit render mode in app XML. It's the only way as it should be. If you ever develop any mobile application, you would likely see the same routine here.
- Furthermore, there is an app xml file in source file. Edit render mode there instead. You don't need to edit your xml file in bin debug folder as the file is auto generated and changed every time you debug.